# Dynamics CRM get extension attribute

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have created a custom field for a system entity. **How do I access the attribute value through XRM web services through late binding?**

I'm using this code but it gives me `EntityReference` object:

```cs
Entity objCase = service.Retrieve("incident", new Guid(Request.QueryString["EntityID"]), attributes);
string strValue = objCase.Attributes["new_papid"]).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are retrieving a lookup value, in this case you need to cast first to Entity Reference

```cs
Entity objCase = service.Retrieve("incident", new Guid(Request.QueryString["EntityID"]), attributes);
EntityReference pap = (EntityReference)objCase.Attributes["new_papid"];
Guid papId = pap.Id; // ID of the record;
string papName = pap.Name; // Primary attribute of the entity;
```